# Owner draw listbox alway return (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)->itemID = -1

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, ownerdrawn

I created an owner draw listbox. Do you know why in **WM_DRAWITEM** message, I only receive `(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam->itemID = -1`?

I'm coding with VS 2010 C++ Express and Win 7.

**Create listbox and set scroll info:**

```
lbHWND = CreateWindowExW(NULL, WC_LISTBOX, NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NODATA | 
    LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT,
    0, 0, 400, 400, tkHWND, (HMENU)IDC_LISTBOX_ENTRY, hInstance, 0);

SCROLLINFO lbSi = { 0 };
lbSi.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
lbSi.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS;
lbSi.nMin = 0;
lbSi.nMax = 1000;
lbSi.nPage = 20;
lbSi.nPos = 0;
SetScrollInfo(lbHWND, SB_VERT, &lbSi, TRUE);
```

**WinProc:**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND phwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_MEASUREITEM:
        {
            MEASUREITEMSTRUCT*  lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
            switch (lpmis->CtlID)
            {
                case IDC_LISTBOX_ENTRY:
                    lpmis->itemHeight = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            DRAWITEMSTRUCT* lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

            // Check lpdis->itemID, for test purpose only
            FILE *f;
            if (!_wfopen_s(&f, L"E:\\lb.txt", L"ab"))
            {
                fprintf(f,"%d\r\n", lpdis->itemID);
                fclose(f);
            }
            // lpdis->itemID always = -1
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added any items to your listbox? It looks like you're adjusting the scrollbar range and expecting that to lead to the listbox drawing items, but it doesn't work that way. The listbox uses the number of items to calculate the scrollbar range, not the other way around.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you're correct, I checked againt and see it is `LBS_NODATA` listbox and I forgot to call `LB_SETCOUNT` message. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer: For an owner draw listbox with `LBS_NODATA` style, I have to tell the listbox number of items it has.

```
SendMessage(lbHWND, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);    // Remove all items, if have any
SendMessage(lbHWND, LB_SETCOUNT, 1000, 0);     // Set number of items (here is 1000)
```